# Specific file permissions in .deb

Tags: debian, file-permissions, packaging

I can create a .deb package successfully with all the file owner fields set correctly. Unfortunately the permission fields are ignores. For example I install one file with:

```
install -v -cm 400 -o ${user} *.pl ${DESTDIR}${dir}
```

but all the files in the package are 644 anyways. How can I force different permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the `dh_fixperms` line in `debian/rules` (should be in the `binary-arch` or `binary-indep` target, as appropriate) and add -Xpath/to/file to that call.

SEE ALSO

`dh_fixperms`(1)